# How to solve WAMP and Skype Conflict in windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, wamp, skype

How do I solve the WAMP and Skype Conflict in windows XP?

My issue is both are working simultaneously when I try to start WAMP

This alert is displayed:

> 'could not execute menu item(internal error)...'

Comment: Shut down one when using another I guess? That being said I find it hard to believe there would be a conflict..how do you know there is?

Comment: maybe a port issue ?
would be weird though

Comment: thanks all My issue is both are didn't working simultaneously when i try to start wamp 'could not execute menu item(internal error)...' this alert is displayed

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP apache server is not starting after Skype installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073985/xampp-apache-server-is-not-starting-after-skype-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generally**
If you have installed Skype with WAMP and if you run Skype before WAMP, you can not get WAMP Apache running. Because both use port 80, there is a conflict.

So before running WAMP be sure that your Skype is disconnected. You can log on Skype after you started WAMP .

In Skype if you click "tools " then "Options > Advanced > Connection" or "Connection options ..."  and connection down the left,,

un-tick the check-box : "use port 80 and 443 as alternative incoming ports"

The problem should be fixed

**In your Case**
You might want to backup Wamp's data (don't forget Mysql and www directory), uninstall the WAMP and install fresh WAMPServer again.

Answer (score 0):

In skype >> 
Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".