# XAMPP apache server is not starting after Skype installation

Tags: apache, xampp, skype

I am getting following console logs:

```
1:14:33 PM  [apache]    Possible problem detected! 
1:14:33 PM  [apache]    Port 80 in use by "c:\program files (x86)\skype\phone\skype.exe"!
1:14:33 PM  [apache]    Possible problem detected! 
1:14:33 PM  [apache]    Port 443 in use by "c:\program files (x86)\skype\phone\skype.exe"!
1:14:33 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
1:14:33 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
1:15:10 PM  [apache]    Starting apache app...
1:15:11 PM  [apache]    Status change detected: running
1:15:11 PM  [apache]    Status change detected: stopped
```

It says 'Status change detected: running' to 'stopped' right away.
I have tried to:

- Turn Off Windows Firewall for internal networks
- Change Port 80 to 99 in httpd.conf file at two locations Listen:80 and ServerName localhost:80
- Change Port 443 to 445 in httpd.conf file at same two locations.
- Apache server is not installed as a Windows service on my machine.
- There is no error or access log generated for today's date.

Comment: Landed here from googling "XAMPP Skype port conflict." The answer by ankyskywalker is better. Please consider accepting that higher-voted answer instead. Your acceptance of the natchiketa led me to try it first. It worked, but is less desirable and it took me more time to restore the original two config files before reconfiguring Skype. Thanks for considering, and thanks to both natchiketa and ankyskywalker for working solutions!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This happened to me while collaborating with someone over Skype, so closing Skype was not an option.

One possible solution is changing the port XAMPP is using for Apache.

### 1. Change *Apache (httpd.conf)*

Go to the XAMPP Control Panel, click *Config* for the Apache module and then *Apache (httpd.conf)*.

[image: XAMPP Control Panel -> Click Config for the Apache module]

[image: Click Apache (httpd.conf) in the new window]

This will now open the configuration file in the editor that is configured in the XAMPP settings (Windows default is notepad.exe). Open the search tool and search for `80`. There should be two lines containing 80 as in the port number 80:

```
Listen 80
```

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

Now replace `80` with an open port. I used `8080`.

```
Listen 8080
```

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

### 2. Change *Apache (httpd-ssl.conf)*

The same procedure needs to be repeated with the SSL configuration. Repeat the steps above but go to *Apache (httpd-ssl.conf)*. Replace the port numbers in the following lines:

```
Listen 443
```

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

```
ServerName www.example.com:443
```

I choose `4433`.

---

**Done.** Click *Start* for Apache and Apache should start fine. On my end, the errors would still show up, though.

Comment: For me this wasn't enough. Had to change some other entries. See [this quick guide](http://el.web.id/how-to-solve-xampp-problem-port-80-443-in-use-by-skype-470)

Comment: @AlaaM. Even with the additional step from the quick guide, the same errors for both ports (80 and 443) persist.

Comment: So if someone breaks into your home, you just let them stay and move out, right? See the other answers for a proper solution, and evict the culprit.

Comment: There seems to be one step missing. In your XAMPP Control Panel, look on the upper-right corner, and you will see Config, with a wrench icon. Click, then look near the bottom right, there is a button that says Service and Port Settings. You have to click that and make the same changes you made in the httpd.conf. Be sure to click save, then click save again (with the green checkmark). Then the red warning text should go away.

Answer (score 117):

go in skype->tools->options->advanced and UN-check use ports 80 & 443.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, 80 is default for www.

Comment: Totally agree with @Mani.

Comment: True, Changing the default port for www could lead to something breaking somewhere.

Comment: there is no option to change the port in new skype

Answer (score 49):

Goto `Skype -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection`

[image: Goto skype -> Tools -> Options -> advanced -> Connection]

[image: Simply Uncheck use port 80 checkbox]

After that, restart your Skype.

**Latest Update**

Skype not using port 80 now:
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-on-desktop

Comment: even it is better to use

Comment: @WaqasAliKhanPuar Skype not using port 80 now. Another application is using port 80 for you.

Answer (score 5):

Opened Skype setting and unchecked the option which says 'Use port 80 as incoming
port' then  I had to start XAMPP server 'as a Administrator'.

Answer (score 0):

It says that skype is using port 80. I would disable skype and then start your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your post with output of the following command, don't forget to correct the path :

```
C:\> path\to\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
```

I think now its not the port conflict issue as you have changed the port.

By the way you can [change the settings](http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/) in skype for not using port 80 and 443, in new version there should be some changes but you should be able to find it. :)

Answer (score 0):

got skype>>tools>>options>>advanced and remove the check on  (use ports 80 & 443).

Answer (score 0):

Since Skype 2019, they are not using port 80, so it no effects on Xampp.
If this problem happened on your computer, try to disable World Wide Web Publishing service by this way:

1. Open CMD
2. Enter services.msc
3. Stop this service: World Wide Web Publishing service

Restart Apache