# Apache won't start on XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, skype

Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

I have checked the `xampp/apache/logs/error.log` file and I found nothing.

I have checked some other application is using port 80 on my PC. The web says that likely the culprit is Skype. I have unchecked *'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections'* option in Skype. But nothing happened. Apache still shutdown by itself.

I also have tried cmd and type `netstat -a -no`. Looking for 127.0.0.1:80 or 192.168.1.100:80, which is using port 80. But, I didn't find any 127.0.0.1:80 or even 192.168.1.100:80 there.

And here's the update from XAMPP.

```
9:25:15 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
9:25:15 PM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "system"!
9:25:15 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
9:25:15 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
9:25:15 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port
```

What's wrong and what should I do?

Comment: you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073985/xampp-apache-server-is-not-starting-after-skype-installation/16870759#16870759) thread

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have iis on your system. Seems like that is using port 80 already.

Open windows services and check.

Answer (score 0):

In skype >>

Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".

then **close your skype and open again.**