# I am not able to Start Apache on XAMPP on my system windows 7 32 bit

Tags: apache, xampp

[image]

I am not able to run/start Apache through XAMPP on my system windows 7 32 bit. The problem is after installing everything is working okay but Apache is not running or starting.

Getting the following error message:-

> Initializing Control Panel    Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate  32-bit
>       Initializing module...
>       Checking for module existence...
>       Checking for required tools...
>       Checking for service (name="Apache2.4"): Service installed
>   error message :     Apache Service detected with wrong path
>   Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
>       Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k

```
Checking default ports...
Executing "net start "Apache2.4""
Return code: 0
```

I think my system is missing Port 80 which is used by Apache server to run - even I checked it on my system but there is no such port 80 on my system.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nothing to do with php, BUT, do you have skype running? If so, try shutting skype down, and I don't mean logout, Right click the skype icon in your process bar and select "Quit", now try to start apache again

Comment: I loved the part about `missing Port 80`. Did you tried to look on computer case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP apache server is not starting after Skype installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073985/xampp-apache-server-is-not-starting-after-skype-installation)

Comment: there is no skype installed on my system

Comment: Still no answer?

Answer (score 1):

Terminate/exit the programs like `skype` and other programs that are using the port 80 then start the `appache server` hope this will start the server. Once appache server start then you can start the skype or other programs.
 Or even you can change the port of appache server. You can follow this link for changing the server port.
[How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Hop this will help you.

Comment: there is no skype installed on my system

Comment: try to change the port number and then check. follow the link.

Comment: exit the xamp and then start the xamp like `Run as Administrator` then start the Apache and mysql it will run the services. I am sure this will work for you.

Comment: hey I have tried that also but getting same error with apache ..i have enclosed screenshot above please see

Comment: reboot your system and try again before starting any program. like antiviruses, skype or others. also allow the Apache access to firewall when you start the appache it prompt for access.

Comment: I am getting this error :   Apache Service detected with wrong path
18:26:17  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
18:26:17  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
18:26:17  [Apache]  Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
18:26:17  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice     how should I change that path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794829/xampp-on-windows-apache-not-starting<br> see this link.

Answer (score 0):

port 80 is a virtual port. It is being used by some other Program. Try executing `netsh` on command prompt. 
The most common issue is skype. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073985/xampp-apache-server-is-not-starting-after-skype-installation) question to resolve it.

Comment: i have not installed skype on my system

Comment: Then use `netsh` to check which program is using port 80

Answer (score 0):

```
Apache Service detected with wrong path Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or Uninstall/disable the other service manually first Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k
```

Your answer is on error message. The installed apache loaction is not inside the xampp folder. Try to reinstall or change the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue on my Windows 10 environment. I've found that I've configured `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf` with a new `SSLCertificateFile` or `SSLCertificateKeyFile` in one of my virtual hosts that was not existing.

So in my httpd-xampp.conf I have the following:

```
## mywebsite.local config
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebsite.local"
    ServerName mywebsite.local
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.local
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebsite.local"
    ServerName mywebsite.local
    ServerAlias *.mywebsite.local
    ## these lines are for my local SSL, here is the issue
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "crt/mywebsite.local/server.crt" ## this path may not exist
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/mywebsite.local/server.key" ## or even this line may not exist
</VirtualHost>
```

I've found that the path from `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` doesn't exist.

I've fixed it and not it's working.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on my system, Windows 10 64bit. I realized that I had edited the httpd.conf file in accordance with a security course I was taking and it rendered my configuration erroneous.

My fix was to uninstall XAMPP from the XAMPP uninstaller located in the XAMPP folder to completely erase all associated files as well as registry files! This was important because I had to do this once before but the uninstaller did not function properly for some reason.

Anyways, completely uninstalling it and reinstalling it leaving all the default settings made it work again. I know how it sounds... delete and re-install, but it finally got my server running, so it might serve as a solution for you and anyone who finds this post. [Image of the Apache and my SQL server running without throwing errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dgqg.png)

Also, I found this out recently:
If you are learning to use XAMPP through a website like stackskills, the modules may not alert you to common issues. For example, if you need to change a directory, from C:/XAMPP/Apache to C:/Hacking Software/XAMPP/Apache, (notice the space and lack of underscore in the first part of the directory "HackingSoftware", XAMPP will read the first "space" as the end of an argument, and so you need to have the entire directory written in quotes like this:  "C:/Hacking Software/XAMPP/Apache" or write it with underscores C:/Hacking_Software/XAMPP/Apache.

This syntax also applies to the use of the "Alias" command. See this link for more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory.

Use this as a resource for other issues: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html